A couple hunted in a forest and black fog
It's a horror movie. I watched it in 2010 or 2011. I just remember:

A couple went to a cafe in a forest.
They saw hunters. The hunters hunted them.
There was also black fog chasing them.
There were also dead soldiers in a cave.
But this was all a dream of an ex-soldier in a hospital. He realized he lost half his body in a war.

The movie is not Johnny Got His Gun or Dog Soldiers.

Hi elif. Please read this page, especially the Identify-This-X section, to see what ID questions should look like.

"forest hunters fog Dead soldiers in cave man woke up in hospital" I'm pretty sure this is punk lyrics! Anyway, is it Johnny Got His Gun?

Sounds like the horror film Shadow from 2009.

Soldier David missed biking while serving in Iraq. Finally at liberty, he bicycles in Europe, heading to Shadow when he stops at a bar and meets the beautiful Angeline. Troublemaker hunters Fred and Buck bother Angeline, so David and the bar owner defend her. As David later camps in the woods, the wind carries away his tent, so Angeline invites him to share hers. As they ride their bicycles together and enjoy the wilderness the next day, they again cross paths with Fred and Buck, who chase the couple with their truck, threatening their lives.

In the end, the whole thing turns out to be David's dream in the hospital, after losing his legs in the war. Here's the trailer:




Wow.that's it.thanks a lot !!!
